# Loop through arrays in arrays in arr

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, excel, moodle

In my moodle web application I have a simple wiki. In the database there is a table called **mdl_wiki_links**. In that table there are the following fields:

- id
- frontpageid
- toppageid

The index page (first page) is the page with id = 109. When I select all records where frontpageid = 109 then I see the following list:

[image]

So I want to add all the page names to an excel file. I can add the above pages to my excel file and under each them their subpages. So for **topageid = 766** I need to

```
select * from mdl_wiki_links where frompageid = 766
```

and so on ... . So I don't know how many will follow.

Which is the best way to loop through this and create an array of them?

Comment: Create a dictionary with topageid as the key and the other fields as an JSON-like array in each key's item.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how I can loop through automatically. Do you maybe have an example?